# Drawing a vertical line in the center of the canvas with fabricjs?

Tags: css, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to draw a line in the exact center of my canvas. Right now I'm using a kind of hacky method.

```
// Centered Line
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/zM63v6J.png', function(myImg) {
  var img1 = myImg.set({
    left: 306,
    selectable: false,
  });
  canvas.add(img1);
});
```

This gets the job done but I'm sure there's a lighter way to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var line = new fabric.Line([canvas.width/2,0,canvas.width/2,canvas.height],{
  strokeWidth:2,
  stroke: 'red',
});
canvas.add(line);
```

```css
canvas{
 border: 2px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

You can use this line coordinate `[canvas.width/2,0,canvas.width/2,canvas.height]` for vertical centre line.